# Surface map generation based on user Geolocation and movement

Tags: javascript, google-maps, react-native, geolocation, surface

I need to create a small web hybrid app that uses google maps to track down users movements and in the end generate a shape on the map with some info like area or distance the user did. The perfect case would be when the surface is a rectangular shape.

I'm thinking of creating a cordova app and use the geolocation api but does the google maps api give me all the other info I need to generate the shape and calculate things like area or height map.

Could this approach work or do you know other open source tools that can help me with this app?